# np.arange(len(dictionnary_new.keys())) AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'keys'

Tags: python, list, dictionary, matplotlib, key

l have a dictionary to display. l want to display only the 15 most common. when l try to display everything it works however when l try to make `.most_common()` l get an error

```
        for t in range(z):
            if text[t] != text2[t]:
                d = (text[t], text2[t])
                dictionnary.append(d)
                print(dictionnary)

dictionnary_new = collections.Counter(dictionnary)

pos = np.arange(len(dictionnary_new.keys()))
width = 1.0

ax = plt.axes()
ax.set_xticks(pos + (width / 2))
ax.set_xticklabels(dictionnary_new.keys())

plt.bar(range(len(dictionnary_new)), dictionnary_new.values(), width, color='g')

plt.show()
```

It works well. However l want to show the 15 most common

```
dictionnary_new = collections.Counter(dictionnary).most_common(15)
```

then l get the following error :

```
    pos = np.arange(len(dictionnary_new.keys()))
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

Comment: that's not possible with the code you posted. You probably already did `dictionnary_new = dictionnary_new.keys()` somewhere, converting to list (python 2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`most_common` returns a list of tuples, not a dict; so that `dictionary_new` is a [misnomer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Misnomer). You can cast to dict type by calling dict on the result:

```
dictionary_new = dict(collections.Counter(dictionnary).most_common(15))
```

Or you could take the keys and values without making the round trip of rebuilding a dict with:

```
keys, values = zip(*collections.Counter(dictionnary).most_common(15))
```